# Using Euros to buy and sell NASDAQ stocks

Tags: stocks, eur-euro, online-brokerage

I'm looking for the best way to buy and sell stock on the NASDAQ using Euros from Spain.  I currently use Charles Schwab to trade in US dollars, but I'm not aware if any similar companies exist in Spain or other parts in Europe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the Spanish market, or any other market in euroland, have the equivalent of ETF's?  If so there ought to be one that is based on something like the US S&P500 or Russell 3000.

Otherwise you might check for local offices of large mutual fund companies such as Vanguard, Schwab etc to see it they have funds for sale there in Spain that invest in the US markets.  I know for example Schwab has something for Swiss residents to invest in the US market.

Do bear in mind that while the US has a stated policy of a 'strong dollar', that's not really what we've seen in practice.  So there is substantial 'currency risk' of the dollar falling vs the euro, which could result in a loss for you.  (otoh, if the Euro falls out of bed, you'd be sitting pretty.)  Guess it all depends on how good your crystal ball is.

Answer (score 3):

Either way you'll be converting to US Dollars somewhere along the line. You are seeking something that is very redundant

Comment: This response did not answer the question at all.

Comment: @JonathanSibley RD's point, perhaps implied, is that you will still need to use USD currency to buy shares on NASDAQ, even if your brokerage account is established in Spain.  So, there will be a conversion from Euros. You can't trade directly in Euros on NASDAQ.  Maybe you could expand on what it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Perhaps I should have first thanked RD for the information, but I am looking for a specific way to buy and sell on the NASDAQ with Euros.  Ideally, it would be fairly black box, wherein I give a broker Euros and they give me NASDAQ shares.  Perhaps the broker will need to convert my Euros to dollars, but this part of the process doesn't concern me.  The answer from @mouviciel points me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the company whose stock you want to buy is present on an european market.

For instance this is the case for Apple at Frankfurt.